# Converting Date in PHP

Tags: php, date, date-format

I have a date in this format`Thu Oct 15 2015 12:51:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and I want to convert this in to PHP date format Y-m-d

Code is as follows

```
$statMonth = 'Thu Oct 15 2015 12:51:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
echo date('Y-m', strtotime($statMonth));
```

returns me `1970-01`

Can you please let me know how to get Month and Year.

Comment: its not duplicate... the above one doesn't help me

Comment: Remove "(India Standard Time)" from $statMonth your code is working fine................. OR replace it with "IST"

Comment: @AjeetKumar, it worked, but the it will be dynamic, per the timezone.. how can I remove it if it dynamic

Comment: @PaulCrovella, sure and thanks

Comment: @KiranKumar Can you add here how you are get the string of GMT time Dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `(India Standard Time)` from your date, You can use following regex to remove dynamically:

```
$statMonth = 'Thu Oct 15 2015 12:51:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
$statMonth = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $statMonth));
echo date('Y-m', strtotime($statMonth));
```

Comment: it worked like charm, what about if preg_replace is deprecated in future.. is there a way we can do it via only date format